# Mandrill: Missing HTML Href URL on received email

Tags: php, api, hyperlink, mandrill

I was just testing the email I sent through Mandrill and found out I cannot click on any content link. When I use the inspect element of my browser, what I found is:

```
<a>Test</a>
```

instead of

```
<a href = "http://test.com">Test</a>
```

This is from Mandrill's API Log:

```
{
    "template_name": "Test_Email",
    "template_content": [
        {
            "name": "email-content",
            "content": "<a href=\\\"http://test.com/\\\">Test</a>"
        }
...
```

What I found suspicious on the above API log is: it has 3 forward slash before and after the true link. I checked the API logs of my other working templates and they only have single forward slashes before and after the true link. So it should look like this:

```
"content": "<a href=\"http://test.com/\">Test</a>"
```

Any idea what happened here?

Here's my PHP code:

```
$mandrill = new Mandrill("KEY_CODE");
$message = array(
    'subject' => $_POST['mass_email_subject'],
    'from_email' => 'noreply@test.com',
    'to' => array(
        array(
            'email' => $user->user_email
        )
    )
);

$template_name = 'Test_Email';
$template_content = array(
    array(
        'name' => 'email-content',
        'content' => $_POST['mass_email_content'] // '<a href = "http://test.com/">Test</a>'
    )
);

$mandrill->messages->sendTemplate( $template_name, $template_content, $message );
```

Comment: Dont put space between `href = "link"`. It always create issue.

Comment: @Yash With or without spaces =  it still does not work. Any other ideas?

Comment: Pass your link inside `$message` as `'text' => $_POST['mass_email_content']`

Comment: @Yash I tried that but anchor tag is still missing the href="http://..."

Comment: Is there neccessary to use `sendTemplate()`...?

Comment: @Yash I've been using the same API code on my other Email Templates, this is the first time I have encountered this issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103925/discussion-between-yash-and-carlo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is to wrap your posted variables with the stripslashes() function of PHP.

```
stripslashes( $_POST['mass_email_content'] );
```